# new password not save in database aftter change password cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, edit, change-password, before-save

Sorry before, may I ask, when change password and forgot password, the new password is not fed stored in the database if my beforeSave function like this :

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
if (!$this->id && !isset($this->data[$this->alias][$this->primaryKey]) && isset($this->data[$this->alias]['password'])) { $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']); } else {
unset($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);
}return true;}
```

But if the function of BeforeSave changed like this

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {  $this->data[$this->alias]['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['password']);}}
```

the value of new password is success save to database, but when the user doing edit function and password left empty, password in database has hashing twice
please help me, thanks before

oh yaa, this is my changePassword function :

```
public function account(){
    if(!$this->Session->check('Auth.User')){
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('You must be logged in to view this page.'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'login'));
    }
    //set user's ID in  model which is needed for validation
    $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id');

    //load the user (avoid populating $this->data)
    $current_user = $this->User->findById($this->User->id);
    $this->set('current_user', $current_user);

    $this->User->useValidationRules('ChangePassword');
    $this->User->validate['re_password']['compare']['rule'] = array('equalToField', 'password', false);

    $this->User->set($this->data);
    if(!empty($this->data) && $this->User->validates()){
        $password = $this->data['User']['password'];
        $this->User->saveField('password', $password);

        $this->Session->setFlash('Your password has been updated');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'account'));
    }

    $this->layout = 'dashboard_admin';
}
```

Comment: Why you are even saving the password in edit. Just unset your password while editing.

Comment: i have been try unset password in edit function but still doesn't work, can you give me example ?

Comment: [This article](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp) might give some more insight in best practices and also shows a behavior driven approach to this issue.

Comment: Always mention CakePHP version. I guess you are using Cakephp 1.3. If it is then both the answer below will not work..

Comment: @FazalRasel i'm using cakephp 2.5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add new form field in edit form, instead of password, add new_password. It will be hashed only if user put somethin in there...

```
public function edit($id = null) {
  $this->User->id = $id;

  if (!$this->User->exists()) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
  }

  if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Saved.', true));

      $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $id));
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error.', true));
    }
  } else {
    $user = $this->User->read(null, $id);
    $this->request->data = $user;

    unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
    $this->set('user', $user);
  }


public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
  if (!empty($this->data['User']['new_password'])) {
    $this->data['User']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['User']['new_password']);

    unset($this->data['User']['new_password']);
  }
}
```

Comment: hey bro, thanks for help, i was try to use it, but when edit users and there is not change data and then submit, password has been hashing twice

Comment: I have edited my answer. Change your edit view so it will use new_password instead of password field

Comment: unset($this->request->data['User']['password']); you should not use this, instead of that you should have used unset($user['User']['password']); before setting the $this->request->data

Comment: @GrzegorzMotyl oke edit users success but when change password, password has been save in database without hashing, like i have password 123456 and then i changed into test123 , password save into database test123 without hashing, any another idea ?

Comment: @Abhishek ya you're right i change unset($this->request->data['User']['password']); into unset($user['User']['password']); 
thanks for the justification

Comment: Thanks all for your help, now its solved
i found in my function change password (account) must change from
$this->User->saveField('password', $password); into $this->User->saveField('password', AuthComponent::password($password));
Thanks a lot friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this only in case of edit (where user is not changing his password) and you should not show even hashed password to your user

```
  if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    unset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
    if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Saved.', true));

      $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $id));
    } else {
      $this->Session->setFlash(__('Error.', true));
    }
  }
```